# Spring Integration DSL: PublishSubscribeChannel order

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to understand how the PublishSubscribeChannel works, so I've implemented a small example:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<?> integerMessageSource() {
    MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
    source.setObject(new AtomicInteger());
    source.setMethodName("getAndIncrement");
    return source;
}



@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(integerMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000)))
        .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .handle(message -> LOG.info("Handling message, step 1: {}", message.getPayload())))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .handle(message -> LOG.info("Handling message, step 2: {}", message.getPayload())))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .transform(source -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("Error").build())
                .handle(message -> {
                    LOG.info("Error");
                }))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .handle(message -> LOG.info("Handling message, step 4: {}", message.getPayload())))
        )
        .get();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

I've expected that I see as an output:

```
Handling message, step 1...
Handling message, step 2...
Error
Handling message, step 4...
```

But the third subflow (with the "Error" output) is always processed first. When I try to define an order I for steps 1, 2, and 4, I get the following console output (warning):

```
o.s.integration.dsl.GenericEndpointSpec  : 'order' can be applied only for AbstractMessageHandler
```

I would have expected that the subscribers gets called in the order of subscription, but this does not seem to be the case.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4 and Spring Integration 4.3.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the lambda handlers are not `Ordered` - the general contract for a pub/sub channel is to invoke `Ordered` subscribers first (in order) and then unordered subscribers.

Since lambdas can't implement multiple interfaces, I am not sure there's anything we can do.

As a work-around, you could do something like...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(integerMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000)))
        .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .handle(handler("Handling message, step 1: {}")))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .handle(handler("Handling message, step 2: {}")))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .transform(message -> "Error")
                .handle(message -> {
                    LOG.info("Error");
                }))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .handle(handler("Handling message, step 4: {}")))
        )
        .get();
    // @formatter:on
}

private MessageHandler handler(String format) {
    return new AbstractMessageHandler() {

        @Override
        protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
            LOG.info(format, message.getPayload());
        }

    };

}
```

So that all the subscribers are `Ordered`.

**EDIT**

Here's a slightly easier workaround - start the subflows with a bridge instead of a lambda so all the subflow first components implement `Ordered`...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(integerMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000)))
        .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .bridge(e -> e.id("s1"))
                .handle(message -> LOG.info("Handling message, step 1: {}", message.getPayload())))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .bridge(e -> e.id("s2"))
                .handle(message -> LOG.info("Handling message, step 2: {}", message.getPayload())))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .transform(source -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("Error").build())
                .handle(message -> {
                    LOG.info("Error");
                }))
            .subscribe(flow -> flow
                .bridge(e -> e.id("s4"))
                .handle(message -> LOG.info("Handling message, step 4: {}", message.getPayload())))
        )
        .get();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, this solved the problem! :) I thought I coud use "order" in .handle() methods, as it is possible for .transform() methods, which also can take a lambda as an input. What is the difference between .handle() and .transform()?

Comment: `.handle(<lambda>)` returns a `MessageHandler` implementation (the lambda). `.transform(..any...)` (even `.transform(<lambda>)`) returns a `MessageTransformingHandler` which implements `Orderable`. For `.transform`, the lambda is a `Transformer`, not a `MessageHandler`.

Comment: I added another work around that requires less code; see the EDIT.
I opened [INT-4347](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4347) to see if we can improve this.