# Spring Integration can’t use multiple Outbound Channel Adapters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

I want to write to a channel adapter only if the previous channel adapter write has been written successfully. I’m trying to do this by:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow buildFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(someChannelAdapter)
         .handle(outboundChannelAdapter1)
         .handle(outboundChannelAdapter2)
         .get();
}
```

But I’m getting the following exception: `The ‘currentComponent’ (…ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter) is a one-way 'MessageHandler’ and it isn’t appropriate to configure ‘outputChannel’. This is the end of the integration flow.`

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your handler implementation is one-way, fire-n-forget, then indeed there is no justification to continue the flow. It can go ahead with the configuration if the current handler is reply-producing and there will be something we can build a message to send to the next channel.

In your case `.handle(outboundChannelAdapter1)` is just `void`, so the next `.handle(outboundChannelAdapter2)` is not going to have anything to continue the flow. So, the framework gives you a hint that such a configuration is wrong. It is called flow for a reason: the result of the current endpoint is going to be an input for the next one. If no result, no continuation. How else it could work in your opinion?

The point is that there need to be something to write to your channel adapter. One of the solution is a `PublishSubscribeChannel` which distributes the same input message to all its subscribers. If that is what would fit to your expectations, then take a look into its support in Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows.

Another way is a `RecipientListRouter` pattern: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter.

You may achieve the same with `WireTap` as well, but it  depends on a business logic of your solution: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-wiretap.

But anyway: you need to understand that the second handler can be called only if there is an input message for its channel. In all those cases I showed you it is exactly the same message you send to a first handler. If your expectations are different, please elaborate what kind of message you'd like to have for a second handler if the first does not return anything.

Comment: I do understand the error and it makes sense. I’ve been also thinking about `PublishSubscribableChannel`, but the thing is that I want the second channel adapter to run only if the message has been successfully written to the first adapter. I couldn’t understand from your answer which pattern lets me continue only after a success.

Comment: The `PublishSubscribeChannel` does that for you by default. See its `ignoreFailures` property which is `false` by default and its `executor` which is also `null` by default. So, if current subscriber fails, the next one is not going to be called. Tell me, please, what lead you think that `PublishSubscribeChannel` works somehow differently?

Comment: See also its docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel

Comment: Since the docs doesn’t have a multiple adapters example I’m relying on this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358840/spring-integration-dsl-publishsubscribechannel-order that looks like what you describe. The latest solution with the bridges is required?

Comment: The first link in my sample shows exactly `publishSubscribeChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows. No, we don't need `bridge()` since some newer version. The order is done implicitly in the `BroadcastPublishSubscribeSpec`.

Comment: Oh I’ve somehow missed that one. That’s great! Thank you very much !

Comment: Do I need to configure a jms  based channel just for this simple need?

Comment: I guess that is fully different story which deserves its own detailed SO thread

Comment: Why? I want to understand in this thread what is the way of writing a super simple code the lets me write to two channel adapters synchronized. The need for BroadcastPublishSubscribe is relevant to here

Comment: It is fully not clear why do you talk about JMS for your task. That's my concern. Unfortunately this is your task and we here know only what you share with us. Therefore JMS word is fully confusing when you show just two plain generic handlers. And I explained you the reason of the error and how to mitigate it in the generic manner as well. So, what drove you to start thinking about JMS in the question where it is not relevant? That's actually one of the advises over here on SO: make your questions as clear as possible without bringing other contexts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask